# Creating directory at wrong place after packaging Electron

Tags: node.js, path, electron

- Electron version: 0.37.5
- Operating system: Ubuntu 15.10

I packaged my project using [electron-packager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-packager). Normally, I create a directory named `downloads` in application directory where my `main.js` file exists. After packaging, I have `locales` and `resources` directories along with other files, and inside `resources` directory, there is another named `app` and there's also `electron.asar` file. Inside `app` folder there are my project files.

When I run the executable, it creates the directory at the same location, instead of creating it under `/resources/app/`. How can I fix this problem?

My `createDirectories` function:

```
// create directory if it does not exist
function createDirectory(directory, callback) {
    Fs.mkdirs(directory, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            return callback();
        }
    })
}
```

I give `downloads/images/` as a parameter to this function, for example. `Fs.mkdirs` is a method of `fs-extra` module.

My directory parameter is `downloads/images/` and `downloads/videos/`

Comment: can you add the code where the `directory` variable is instanciated ?

Comment: @KeitIG I added to the end.

Comment: This will not answer your question, but Vladim is right. You should place your files in `app.getPath('userData').`

Comment: @KeitIG oh, it actually did. and it makes so much more sense. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing app data to the application installation directory is generally a bad idea since the user running the app may not have permission to write files to the application installation directory. What you should probably do instead is store whatever your application downloads at the location returned by [`app.getPath('userData')`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v0.37.6/docs/api/app.md#appgetpathname).

Comment: That solved the problem, and it makes much more sense. Thanks.